# Regular expression for string having character w or may not be in starting and numbers at the end

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate a string having one or more "w" at the starting and one number at the end or may not be.
I used `$regEx="/([w])([1-9])/";`  but its not working

example of valid string

```
w1
wwwwww52
w
```

example of invalid string

```
2w
1
wwwx22
wa1
```

Comment: `I want to validate a string having one or more "w" ` then why you added `1` to the valid strings list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the capture groups, but you will need quantifiers and anchors:

```
$regEx= "/^w+[1-9]*$/";
```

Or if your input must accept `0` as a number as well, then you need to add that or use `\d`:

```
$regEx= "/^w+[0-9]*$/";

$regEx= "/^w+\d*$/";
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string while `$` matches the end of the string.

`+` makes the regex match at least 1 of the preceding character/group.

`*` makes the regex match 0 or more times, the preceding character/group.

Comment: @pritinarang That was a small change. Edited answer

Comment: @pritinarang Great! Consider clicking on the tick outline to mark the answer as accepted and your question as solved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
I think that should be like this
$regEx="/^w+\d*/";
```